# disable click on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to have this animation is only possible vom top 0 to 200 when i scroll to 201 this click animation is disabled. How is that possbile?

I need this because wenn i click on the navigation it slides to top so i cant see anymore my navigation.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200)
    {
        $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {anim10();});
    } 
    else
    {     
       $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {disabled();}); 
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UqgXc/38/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use unbind the click function by using [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) or if you are using old version of jquery use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200)
    {
        $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {anim10();});
    } 
    else
    {     
       $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").off('click')); 
    }
});
```

Comment: no this is not working... now the animation starts not when im on top in the 0-200 Area :/ Why?